# download a .gz file from a subdirectory in a s3 bucket using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have a file named combine.gz which I need to download from a subfolder on s3 . I am able to get to the combine.gz files (specifically one per directory) but I am unable to find a method in boto to read the .gz files to my local machine.

All I can find are the `boto.utils.fetch_file`, `key.get_contents_to_filename` , `key.get_contents_to_file` methods all of which as I understand, directly stream the contents of the file.

Is there be a way for me to first read the compressed file in .gz format onto my local machine from S3 using boto and then uncompress it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What, to you, is the difference between "stream the contents of the file" and "read the file"? They sound like synonyms to me.

Comment: Do you need boto for this? Why not just download the file with urllib or requests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading the files from s3 recursively using boto python.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063474/downloading-the-files-from-s3-recursively-using-boto-python)

Comment: Also, there are no directories in s3, sub- or otherwise

Comment: streaming the file may refer to chunking, versus reading into memory and then writing out.  get_contents_as_string or get_contents_to_file.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the full contents as a string and then manage it as a string object.  This is very dangerous and could lead to memory or buffer issues so be careful.

Check into using cStringIO.StringIO, gzip.GzipFile, and boto

```
datastring = key.get_contents_as_string()
data = cStringIO.StringIO(datastring)
rawdata = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=data).read()
```

again - be careful as this has lots of memory and potential security issues in the event the gzip file is malformed.   You'll want to wrap with try, except and code defensively if you don't control both sides.