# Python - Download data from specific folder / sub - folder AWS S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to extract data from AWS S3. The code below helps me download a file. However if the bucket has multiple folders then the below code tries to extract the complete bucket and not a specific folder / sub-folder. How could I modify the below code to extract only a specific file in a folder / sub-folder

```
from boto3.session import Session
import boto3

ACCESS_KEY = 'ABC'
SECRET_KEY = 'XYZ'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
          aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
your_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

for s3_file in your_bucket.objects.all():
    print(s3_file.key)

your_bucket.download_file('rawdata.xlsx' ,/Users/user/Desktop/folder/')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading the files from s3 recursively using boto python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063474/downloading-the-files-from-s3-recursively-using-boto-python)

Comment: Are you wanting to "only a specific file in a folder / sub-folder", or do you want the code to copy all the files in that directory and subdirectory? Do you also want it to recreate the folder hierarchy locally?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , yes I am trying to copy contents of a specific folder copied to my local. Source has multiple folders and I am trying to download only from few specific folders and would like to define the locations in the script.

Comment: Please note that if you are downloading files to your local computer and you want to re-create the folder hierarchy, your code will also have to create the directories before downloading files into those directories. Some examples are on [amazon s3 - Downloading the files from s3 recursively using boto python. - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063474/downloading-the-files-from-s3-recursively-using-boto-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download specific files, you should create a list of the files to be downloaded. then, you can check if the file matches, then download it.

```
files_to_downloaded = ["folder1/key.png", "folder2/other.png", "folderRandom/Randomkey.png"]
for fileObject in bucket.objects.all():
    file_name = str(fileObject.key)
    if file_name in files_to_downloaded:
        bucket.download_file(file_name, 'destination_path')
```

Comment: Hi @bughunter, I have updated the code as mentioned however I get the below error

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Code :

your_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname')

#for s3_file in your_bucket.objects.all():
#    print(s3_file.key)


files_to_downloaded = ["main/sub/file1.txt","main/sub1/file2.txt"]
for fileObject in bucket.objects.all():     <---- Error points to this line
    file_name = str(fileObject.key)
    if file_name in files_to_downloaded:
        bucket.download_file(file_name, '/Users/user/Desktop/folder/')

Could you please assist.

Comment: @Taukheer Rather than putting code in comments, feel free to Edit your question.

Comment: @Taukheer, can you please update the question, what you have tried. it really hard to read code in comments.

Comment: @BugHunter, I was able to extract the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: @Taukheer, Great :) if you found this answer helpful, then please accept it.